# JWplayer doesn't play video fast

Tags: flash, jwplayer

I use `jwplayer 7` for my website. The video we are using are `MP4` formats.

My problem is `jwplayer` star playing the videos only after they load and I don't want that.

Is there any setting or configuration or tricks for that?

[sample link from **my** site](http://mobile-tv.ir/#/product/?id=3843)

In this website Android app, this problem didn't exist.

Comment: MP4 needs metadata to play video (tells where each frame starts etc in the bytes). Your video has this metadata at the **back** end of file bytes. Hence **all** bytes must load before reaching metadata for correct playback to begin. You can google a free video tool to move the data to front of file for you

Comment: For example.. If you use **[FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)** ( direct d/load for **[windows version](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)**) then when installed you can use this command `ffmpeg -i myInputVideo.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -movflags +faststart myOutputName.mp4` and that will simply move the metadata without changing anything (takes 1 or 2 seconds to do that) and test the output file.

Comment: but android app of this website have no such problem with this video files , is there different between android player and browser player for load video file ?

Comment: All I know is your example link videos have a problem. FFmpeg is a good solution cos it will handle multiple videos (in a folder) with one command etc. Differences in player code are possible. Some are clever enough to look for the correct information, some just wait for it to be available. Dont rely on finding the correct player, **just fix the files**, then your visitor's any preferred player/browser now becomes the correct player.

Comment: hello again , i contact to owner of website , i just a programmer , there is a thausend of videos , i test videos with video tag in opera and video play very well .... they see that and say , so this can be fix without convert , please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't like the answer, I appreciate your site has many (thousands?) of video files and it's gunna be a mission to edit each one. If they were all edited & saved from one program that means they all have this problem. If you receive videos from various sources then some files may be okay.

About the problem files. Like I said in the comments, your link has videos with metadata at the **back end** of file. I know this because I checked the bytes already.

Look at this image of bytes of **AzhanceShisheii_128.hugg.mp4** as sampled from your link...

The file correctly begins with **ftyp** at (1), but then at (2) it says **mdat**. MDAT is the audio/video frame bytes all mixed up in any order.
So how does video player know which bytes are for frame 1 image and bytes for sound of frame 1? It checks metadata section called **moov**. The previous 4 bytes show size of sections, here the hex value of  `09 DE AD 0E` means a size of 165.6 mb (check **[here](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter)**). So until 165 megabytes are downloaded, Player cannot even know where any frame 1 data is to display a picture (there is no rule that **mdat** content must be in order of appearance).

You have to edit your files so its small **moov** metadata first then large **mdat** after, not what you have now which is...  large **mdat** first then later followed by small **moov** metadata.

[image: MDAT vs MOOV bytes at front example]

Comment: hello again , i contact to owner of website , i just a programmer , there is a thausend of videos , i test videos with video tag in opera and video play very well .... they see that and say , so this can be fix without convert , please help

Answer (score 0):

What is the behavior you're trying to achieve? Not autostarting video? From the JWP side, you can set autostart to true (or false). Default behavior is autostart: false.

Here is an article that you may find helpful that details how to autostart on page load: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1428525-autostarting-on-page-load

Comment: no , my problem is when you click on play , first play take long time , and its like hole video downloaded with player and after that video is showing

Comment: Can you provide a link?